# Set frame to UIview which is child view of UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiscrollview

I have created one `UIView` inside the `UIScrollView` from storyboard, Above `UIView` some more views will be present like label, imageview etc inside `UIScrollView`.

I want to set the frame to UIView programatically. I have tried to set frame using **setFrame** function programatically, but its not working for the `UIView` which is inside `UIScrollView`.

I have seen similar questions like this, but everywhere create the UIView programmatically, but I want to use the `UIView` created in storyboard and want to set the frame to that.

Can anybody please suggest me, how can i do this?

Thanks.

Edit1: Added the code

```
[myownview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 110)];
```

myownview is UIView added inside UIScrollView, write above code inside viewDidLoad method.

Edit2:

```
 NSString userText = @"Some long text which is multiple lines";

 CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(200, 90000.0f);

 // Get the size of the text given the CGSize we just made as a constraint
 CGSize size = [userText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

 UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20, size.width, size.height)];
[myLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[myLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13];
[myscrollView addSubview:myLabel];

[myownview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, myLabel.frame.origin.y+myLabel.frame.size.height+10, 320, 110)];
```

I have create the IBOutlets properly.

```
myscrollview frame is (0, 135, 320, 298) on storyborad

myownview frame is (0, 214, 320, 110) on storyborad inside myscrollview
```

I have set the contentsize to myscrollview as below

```
myscrollView.contentSize =  CGSizeMake(320, 600);
```

now want to change the origin of myownview.

Most impornatant condition is Autolayout is **"TRUE"**.

Comment: put some code what you've tried and what's not worked for you

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I have write the code above.

Comment: you want to change frame after some event? like when i press button then the frame of view should change to other frame?

Comment: no, Above myownview one programmatically added UILabel is present I had set the height programatically to that UILabel properly,now i want to shift the origin of myownuiview according to size of UILabel, all things should be done on load only, no other event is needed.

Comment: height of that programmatically created UILable is fixed? if so then calculate the height+origin of that UILable and set your UIView's origin according to the total of that UILable else paste the code of the stuff you setting so that i can take a look an help you out because your problem looks very simple and easy to resolve

Comment: hey Meenakshi i've tried your code and it returns the perfect value try to log your myownview and take a look it will return you the desired frame not getting what's the issue with you

Comment: it still works perfect after i've done the same thing you did in updates i think there might me some problem of referencing or you need to restart your xcode once.

Comment: and the myownview frame is display in nslog is proper, but not display on emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Autolayout is True, I have resolved above by adding the myownview programmatically into scrollview.

```
myownview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, myLabel.frame.origin.y+myLabel.frame.size.height+10, 320, 110);

[myscrollView addSubview:myownview];

myscrollView.contentSize =  CGSizeMake(320, myownview.frame.origin.y+myownview.frame.size.height+10);
```

Otherwise, when Autolayout is False, then both answers provided by "eptdeveloper" and "preetam" are correct.

Answer (score 2):

make outlet of that view from storyboard to respective class.

refer to the created view like:
but here no need to allocate it again.just change the frame.

```
[self.newView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 80)];
```

If you are setting the frame which leads to out of scrollview,then you are unable to see that view.

**View will only visible in the scrollview area.**

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, trying above code, but its not working.

Comment: have you made connection(IBOutlet) of view from IB to ur class?

Comment: @preetan, yes already tried the above code, added it on my question only, and I have already create the IBOutlet from storyboard for myownview. Setting frmae is not create problem for any view which is inside UIView, but problem with view which is inside UIScrollView.

Comment: @Meenakshi: I checked now,Its working...tell me more abt ur scrollview.  make sure it is more wider than ur view?

Comment: myscrollview frame is (0, 135, 320, 298)

myownview frame is (0, 214, 320, 110) on storyborad,

I have set the contentsize to myscrollview as 
myscrollView.contentSize =  CGSizeMake(320, 600);
as want to change the origin of myownview.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36761/discussion-between-preetam-and-meenakshi)